# Exclude folder from refreshing browser-sync with NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, browser-sync

I'm trying to get `browser-sync` to ignore one of my folders, and I've [taken example code used in a tutorial](https://github.com/wesbos/css-grid/blob/master/package.json) from `wesbos`

This is my attempted `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "linkup-paints",
  "description": "NPM for Linkup Paint Supplies website for 2019",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "run-script-os",
    "start:win32": "browser-sync start --server --files '**/*.css, **/*.html, **/*.js, !node_modules/**/*' --directory --port 7777 --browser \"C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Developer Edition\\firefox.exe\"",
    "build-sass": "node-sass styles/main.scss css/main.css",
    "watch-sass": "node-sass -w styles/main.scss css/main.css"
  },
  "author": "dpDesignz",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "run-script-os": "^1.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.4"
  }
}
```

I've tried changing this line

```
"start:win32": "browser-sync start --server --files '**/*.css, **/*.html, **/*.js, !node_modules/**/*' --directory --port 7777 --browser \"C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Developer Edition\\firefox.exe\""
```

to this:

```
"start:win32": "browser-sync start --server --files '**/*.css, **/*.html, **/*.js, !node_modules/**/*, !styles/**/*' --directory --port 7777 --browser \"C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Developer Edition\\firefox.exe\""
```

and this:

```
"start:win32": "browser-sync start --server --files '**/*.css, **/*.html, **/*.js, !node_modules/**/*, !styles/**' --directory --port 7777 --browser \"C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Developer Edition\\firefox.exe\""
```

but it still reloads my `browser-sync` when I change a file in the `styles` folder. I'm sure this is a simple fix, but I can't seem to see it.